# How can I disable client-side SSL renegotiation with HAProxy

Tags: ssl, haproxy

HAProxy as of 1.5dev supports SSL, but I'm trying to disable client-side renegotiation requests as it can be a form of DoS with the correct tool for the exploit. Has anybody found a flag or patched HAProxy to disable this?

Answer (score 0):

Two things in your config -

1. Does the server line have 'ssl' in it? It should not be there if re-negotiation is to be avoided.
   e.g. server  ip:port check inter... ssl
2. Does the frontend/listen block have 'ssl' with the bind statement? Only then will ssl be terminated at haproxy level.